# Getting strange output when printing sorted array in C

Tags: c

I am working on a program that takes an arbitrary number of arguments from the command line, cuts them in half, puts them in an array, sorts them alphabetically, then prints them in order. It works fine up to three arguments, but is giving some strange output after that. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ca9q.png) Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct string {
    char *first_half;
    char *second_half;
};

int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b);
int arrayIndex = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numArguments = argc; 
    char **new_array = malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));
    struct string word;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) 
    {
        int len = strlen(argv[i]);
        int len_first = len/2;
        int len_second = len - len_first;

        word.first_half = malloc( (len_first + 1) * sizeof(char) );
        word.second_half = malloc( (len_second + 1) * sizeof(char) );

        memcpy(word.first_half, argv[i], len_first);
        memcpy(word.second_half, argv[i]+len_first, len_second);

        new_array[arrayIndex] = word.first_half;
        if(word.second_half != " ")
            new_array[arrayIndex+1] = word.second_half;

        arrayIndex += 2;

        //free(word.first_half);
        //free(word.second_half);
    }

    qsort(new_array, ((argc - 1)*2), sizeof(char *), cstring_cmp);

    for (int i = 0; i < ((argc - 1)*2); ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", new_array[i]);
    }

  return 0;
}

int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

Comment: Please do include those strange outputs in the post.

Comment: Just added it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the last characters for `word.first_half` and `word.second_half` to `'\0'`. Therefore the comparison function will have undefined behavior in the call `strcmp` and so will `printf`, because both of them expect pointers to null-terminated strings.

Also you are not allocating enough for `new_array`. It will have to contain twice `argc-1` elements.

`if(word.second_half != " ")` also causes problems should it not trigger, because you are leaving the position in `new_array` that would be filled uninitialized, and so the functions mentioned above will get invalid pointers.